# jquery - Replace an element from the cloned html

Tags: html, jquery

I want to achieve the below two scenarios:

1. Need to add rows on click of the plus button.
2. Need to replace the plus button with a hyperlink from the dynamically added rows.

```
<button type="button" class="addRow" />+</button>
```

Replace the above button with the below for all the dynamically added rows.

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" title="Click to remove">Remove</a>
```

I've done the first scenario and stuck with the second one.

HTML:

```
<table id="exampleTbl">  
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>
           <button type="button" class="addRow" />+</button>
       </td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>
           <button type="button" class="addRow" />+</button>
       </td>  
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#exampleTbl').delegate('button.addRow', 'click', function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // get the parent row of the clicked button
        var html = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
        $(html).insertAfter(row); // insert content
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#exampleTbl').delegate('button.addRow', 'click', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // get the parent row of the clicked button
    var html = $(this).closest('tr').clone();
    $(html).insertAfter(row); // insert content
    
    let btn = $('<a href="javascript: void(0)" title="Click to remove">Remove</a>');
    btn.click(function () {
      $(html).remove(); // Remove row on click
    })
    
    $(html).find('.addRow').replaceWith(btn);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="exampleTbl">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="addRow">+</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="addRow">+</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j18yfwLv/1/

**Note**: I just replaced the button with the content you wanted, do you want the button to remove the row as well?

Comment: Thanks. $(document).on("click", "a.remove-type" , function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        }); - I've added this to your code which is removing the row.

Comment: Plz correct if there is a better way to remove the row.

Comment: There are definitely cleaner approaches to doing this, but I think if it's working for you that should be good enough. I've added another approach in my answer :)